# mod_rewrite: setting GET depending on HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, get

I recently discovered the power of the mod_rewrite module and I need some help with it.

Say I have a website which has two domain names mapping to the same host...

```
example.com
example.net
```

And I would like to set a GET var depending on the the HTTP_HOST (i.e. .com OR .net ?) ...

```
/index.php?lang=en
/index.php?lang=es
```

However the caveat is this.. I already have 3 RewriteRules...

```
RewriteRule ^(about|contact)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC]
...
..
```

And if I were to follow the example over [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) (bottom of RewriteCond) I would have to copy the 3 RewriteRules for each HTTP_HOST (i.e. .com OR .net) and add the GET var statically like; &lang=en OR &lang=es and the end of each rule...

Is there some way to do this automatically without having to copy the 3 rules all over again which only differ by just one get var at the end?

PS. I know this can be done through the scripting language, but I was wondering if this can be done through mod_rewrite, and how.

thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting something like this before all your other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=en [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=es [QSA]
```

Although you might be better off using an environment variable to specify the language, using the `SetEnv` directive with a different language in each virtual host.

Or maybe even better yet, look into [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), which contains some standard capabilities for dealing with languages.

Comment: I'll check out that QSA flag.. seems promising.

Comment: While the code submtited was of great help, it's useless on it's own. You'll be left with infinite recursion, since apache will keep on redirecting each page to ?lang=en|es even if this has already been set..

So add the following line before: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(lang=(en|es))

this will not redirect to ?lang=en|es if it has already been set ;)

Comment: There shouldn't be any infinite recursion unless you restart the rule rewriting process at some point later on. From your question I believed you weren't doing that.